# Adding a new test case to a TensorFlow DNNClassifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, machine-learning

Take this example- https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator

I want to know how to add a new training case. That is. Suppose the classifier is being trained on 25 rows (saved in csv format). Now we do not have the csv anymore. We just have the saved model which we are using for testing later on. How do we add another single training case (a single row of csv file), to the model? Any ideas?

Comment: Reminds me of transfer learning.

Comment: Any idea how to implement it? Stuck badly for a few days.

Comment: Since you have the model perhaps setting the weights and biases from the model and optimizing might get you the results..

Comment: How do I get weights and biases from TensorFlow’s high-level machine learning API (tf.estimator)?